# How to do hg tasks workflow?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I now have good experience with basic mercurial operations, but would like to work in a task driven manner. I have come across the [hg tasks](https://bitbucket.org/alu/hgtasks/wiki/Home) extension which like a good idea. In particular, I like the workflow explained at http://x.zpuppet.org/2009/03/09/mercurial-tasks-extension/.

Using the `hg tasks` extension, one can define a number of tasks, list them, and work on each of them. A task would be in one of the states: new, active, or complete.

Unfortunately, the `hg tasks` extension seems to not be updated in quite a while. So my question is: is there a simple way to carry out the same workflow using a different extension or through the basic capabilities of Mercurial (branching, bookmarks, etc)?

I am looking to use this in my personal projects, so assume a lone developer if need be.

Comment: Are any of the [open issues](https://bitbucket.org/alu/hgtasks/issues?status=new&status=open) show-stoppers for you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I haven't actually tested. But the extension was last updated for mercurial 1.9 and we are at 2.5 I believe. And two of the open issues seem to be crashes. Doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use named branches: branch per task and variations of `push -b` (which will include only needed for push branches) or `push -r` (where revset with revset's language forms forms set /*by some way*/ of only needed branch's heads)